# Stimulsoft StiMvcViewer can't "save as"

Tags: stimulsoft

stimulsoft  StiMvcViewer  can't "save as"

Server Error in '`/`' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description:

```
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added the necessary actions for the Viewer.

```
"MvcViewer1", new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
Actions =
{
    GetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
    ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
}
```